# Creating a mysql custom function to import data from txt file

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

i want to create a mysql function which should import data from txt file to mysql table.

Here is what i have done so far:

opened create new function, name the function `load_file_txt`
then i added these lines

```
LOAD DATA INFILE `data_file.txt`
INTO TABLE `reservation_general`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY `,`
LINES TERMINATED BY `\n`
```

so that the whole function is now like this

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    FUNCTION `customsearch`.`load_file_txt`()
    RETURNS TYPE
    BEGIN

LOAD DATA INFILE `data_file.txt`
INTO TABLE `reservation_general`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY `,`
LINES TERMINATED BY `\n`
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Im using SQL Yog also mysql workbench is installed.
Here is some of the data in the txt file.

```
0806,,Adolfo,Castro,CHECKED IN,5123551,5262313,11.09.14,01.12.14,XLOG,0,,
0807,Mr.,Matthew,Keehn,CHECKED IN,4942796,5091556,02.08.14,23.10.14,XBUG,1,,
0808,,Gregory,Jamison,CHECKED IN,5003068,5143829,15.08.14,15.10.14,XLOG,4,,
0901,Mr.,Mohan,Raj,CHECKED IN,4909299,5056058,24.07.14,24.10.14,XKLG,4,,
0901,Mr.,Asif,Azmi,CHECKED IN,4909305,5056066,24.07.14,24.10.14,XKLG,0,,
0901,Mr.,Sriram,Ramamoorthy,CHECKED IN,4909304,5056065,24.07.14,24.10.14,XKLG,0,,
0901,Mr.,Vimmal,Thundiyil,CHECKED IN,4909302,5056063,24.07.14,24.10.14,XKLG,0,,
0904,Mr.,Nasser,AL Khater,CHECKED IN,5187812,5325323,25.09.14,27.09.14,XOTG,2,0803,
0905,,Zoe,Treble,CHECKED IN,5003063,5143824,15.08.14,15.10.14,XLOG,1,,
0906,Mr.,Timo,Hornacek,CHECKED IN,4990560,5133071,06.08.14,29.09.14,XLOG,0,,
0906,,Urban,Petra,CHECKED IN,4990561,5133072,06.08.14,29.09.14,XLOG,0,,
0906,Mr.,Lauris,Coucaud,CHECKED IN,4990556,5133067,06.08.14,29.09.14,XLOG,0,0801,
0906,Mr.,Viliam,Fercak,CHECKED IN,4990559,5133070,06.08.14,29.09.14,XLOG,0,,
0906,,Jakub,Novotny,CHECKED IN,4990558,5133069,06.08.14,29.09.14,XLOG,0,,
0906,Mr.,Faria,Rodrigo,CHECKED IN,4990555,5133066,06.08.14,29.09.14,XLOG,0,,
0906,Mr.,Yannis,Michalandos,CHECKED IN,4968820,5113842,02.08.14,29.09.14,XLOG,6,0908,
0907,Mr.,Keoki,Sears,CHECKED IN,4878044,5024305,04.08.14,29.10.14,XBUG,1,,
0908,Mr.,Zacharias,Vailakis,CHECKED IN,4704796,4858307,07.08.14,07.11.14,XLOG,2,0903,
1001,Ms,Shahla,Jassim,CHECKED IN,5003076,5143837,15.08.14,15.10.14,XKLG,5,,
1002,Mr.,Pedro Luis,Gonzalez,CHECKED IN,4845808,4994067,12.09.14,12.12.14,T22G,2,1002,
1003,Dr,Hadi,Abderrahim,CHECKED IN,4918568,5066577,12.07.14,12.10.14,XOTG,1,1003,
1004,Ms,Aisha,Siyam,DUE OUT,5191796,5328567,25.09.14,26.09.14,XOTG,1,,
1005,Mr.,William Krik,Brooks,CHECKED IN,5003297,5143844,15.08.14,15.10.14,XLOG,2,,
1006,Miss,Tatenda,Mutsonziwa,CHECKED IN,5084546,5223307,01.09.14,02.12.14,XLOG,0,1006,
1006,Mr.,Vlad,Mihovilovic,CHECKED IN,4995048,5137059,01.09.14,02.12.14,XLOG,3,,
1006,Mr.,Vishal,Rander,CHECKED IN,5084552,5223313,01.09.14,02.12.14,XLOG,0,4403,
1007,Mr.,Robert Leonard,Costello,CHECKED IN,5035052,5174565,28.08.14,28.11.14,XBUG,1,1007,
1008,Mr.,Yousif Bani,Yassen,CHECKED IN,5033309,5172314,01.09.14,01.12.14,XLOG,1,1008,
1008,,TBA,Qatar University 04,CHECKED IN,4952550,5101560,01.09.14,01.12.14,XLOG,3,1008,
1101,,Klara,Steinwender,CHECKED IN,4994553,5136815,07.08.14,29.09.14,XKLG,1,,
1101,,Teeranpong,Jaro,CHECKED IN,4994552,5136814,07.08.14,29.09.14,XKLG,1,,
1101,Mr.,Yannis,Michalandos,CHECKED IN,4919806,5068064,09.07.14,29.09.14,XKLG,1,0908,
1101,,Luca,Luca,CHECKED IN,4923310,5071319,10.07.14,29.09.14,XKLG,0,,
1102,Mr.,Martin,Marks,CHECKED IN,4896312,5042072,30.06.14,30.09.14,T22G,2,1102,
1103,Mr.,Jonathan,Collier,CHECKED IN,5123806,5262564,26.09.14,10.10.14,XOTG,1,1103,
1104,Mr.,Ryan,Bowd,CHECKED IN,4922299,5070311,31.07.14,31.10.14,XOTG,1,1104,
1105,,TBA,Qatar University 05,CHECKED IN,4862801,5010813,01.09.14,01.12.14,XLOG,3,1105,
1106,Ms,Wendy,Isaacs,CHECKED IN,5003066,5143827,15.08.14,15.10.14,XLOG,4,,
1107,Mr.,Fakhri,Nawahda,CHECKED IN,4938054,5087066,02.08.14,02.10.14,XBUG,1,1107,
1108,Mr.,Nicolas,Renna,CHECKED IN,5166547,5305058,21.09.14,30.09.14,XLOG,0,,
1108,Mr.,Ali,Haidary,CHECKED IN,5166546,5305057,21.09.14,30.09.14,XLOG,3,1608,
```

after trying to run this above function i get this error.

```
Query: CREATE FUNCTION `customsearch`.`load_file_txt`() RETURNS TYPE BEGIN LOAD DATA INFILE `data_file.txt` INTO TABLE `reservation_gen...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE
    BEGIN
LOAD DATA INFILE `data_file.txt`
INTO TABLE `reservation_general`' at line 3

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec
```

i dont know why i am getting this error. Hoping if anyone can help me creating the function to read the the data from file and import it in to mysql table.

Comment: `RETURNS TYPE` looks wrong

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
it was already written there.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
i removed that line still getting the error.

Comment: Well a function needs to return _something_, you can't just remove the `return` when you declare a function. Please read the manual.